# I have python's sqlite3 module. Do I still need to install SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, installation, python-module

Noob here just started exploring SQLite lately and have been using Python's sqlite3 module, so far so good.
Except today when I typed `sqlite3` directly into the terminal and got

```
"The program 'sqlite3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install sqlite3"
```

Same thing when I typed in `sqlite`.

That came as a surprise because according the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), isn't `sqlite3` just a "DB-API 2.0 (whatever that means) interface for SQLite databases"? If it's just a wrapper, how have I been able to run SQLite commands with this module without the "real" SQLite library installed? Unless Python's `sqlite3` come with its own pre-compiled SQLite and doesn't need to use the "real" one in the environment...

BTW I do see a `libsqlite3` package on my machine but running `man libsqlite3`, `apropos libsqlite3`, `libsqlite3` give me nothing.

Comment: Module _sqlite3_ comes with Python. It's mostly written in C; also called a C extension (_\_sqlite3.so_, that also comes with Python). That depends on the sqlite lib itself (on my RH7 machine it's _/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0_). On Windows for example, _libsqlite..._ (or it's dll correspondent), also comes with Python. Regarding Linux i guess the answer to your question is __YES__, you have to have an _sqlite_ version (compatible to the one that Python C extension was compiled against) on your system.

Comment: _"Unless Python's sqlite3 come with its own pre-compiled SQLite and doesn't need to use the "real" one in the environment..."_ This is exactly what it does.

Comment: Thanks! Just confirmed: installed `SQLite version 3.8.10.2`, but python `sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.3.1'`. The terminology "SQL interface" sure was confusing